# how to dynamically update table view in IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

i have a table and custom cells created dynamically, i have a http asyn call which gets me JSON data, now i need to update the table cells with the data received...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Call:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: isn't it reload complete table again, if YES then What to do to refresh Visible Cells !!

Answer (score 7):

Have to NSNotification, one in the loadview and another one in the

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

delegate method , like this:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateTable) name:@"downloadCompleted" object:nil];
```

The above one in loadview method and the following one in the delegate

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"downloadCompleted" object:nil];
```

the updateTable method will be called once data is obtained from JSON parsing. You can call the reloadData method of the tableview in this method to fill the tableview with obtained values.... Hope this helps.. Cheers...Happy coding..

Comment: You need to have notifications because u dunno when the data fetching is getting completed from the URL..... Hope u can get me...

Answer (score 0):

call the table reloadData instance method . where ever you want to update the data of table.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a bit more context using `swift`.
If you are trying to do this from a class that implements `UITableViewController` it will have a property `tableView` upon which you can call `tableView.reloadData()`.

For example:

```swift
import UIKit

class TableViewController implements UITableViewController {
  private func changeData() -> Void {
   //... changes data
   tableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

Source: [*UITableViewController*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcontroller)